# SSH ProxyJump on macOS Catalina is not working

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, openssh, macos-catalina

I have 3 Computers: 
    1. my mac with macOS Catalina 
    2. my 1st Raspberry Pi
    3. my 2nd Raspberry Pi

On my mac is ssh running version: OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

I am able to log into each raspberry pi separately via ssh.

I want to ssh from my mac to the 2nd Pi by jumping over the 1st Pi. Like this:

```
+-------+       +--------+       +--------+
|  Mac  | ----> | raspi1 | ----> | raspi2 |
+-------+       +--------+       +--------+
```

with this .ssh/config file:

```
Host 1pi
    HostName raspi1
    User pi
    #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host 2pi
    HostName raspi2
    User pi
    ProxyJump 1pi
    #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Though I am able to log into the 1st Raspberry Pi, I am always getting the same error when attempting to log into the 2nd Pi.

```
$ ssh 2pi
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
```

I have even tried it with the IdentityFile parameter and just using the -J option. But still the same result.

```
$ ssh -J pi@raspi1 pi@raspi2
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
```

I tried it on macOS Mojave and it worked. I tried it on Linux and it worked.

How do I get it to work on macOS Catalina?
How can I jump to the 2nd Pi over the 1st Pi?

When I do `ssh 2pi -vv` I get this (among other debug information)

```
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: \033[H\033[2JSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u1
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
debug1: channel 0: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for raspi2 port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 1.
```

Comment: First figure out _why_ it doesn't work... use `ssh -vv` to see the actual banner being sent.

Comment: Yes, I can `ssh raspi2` from within `raspi1`

Comment: That banner looks like it starts with escape sequences to clear the screen and put the cursor at the top left. Do you have a login/profile file on the 1st Pi that tries to reset the terminal?

Comment: Where do I find a login/profile file?

Comment: @Hendrik Look on raspi1, for something like `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/bashrc` (assuming you're using bash as your shell on that system; if not, similar names for whatever shell you are using).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's just a bandaid, but you can `brew install openssh` and `brew link openssh`. Everything seems to work with OpenSSH_8.2p1, except for `UseKeychain` if that's something you use.

Answer (score 5):

OpenSSH_8.1p1 has a bug that swapped `%n` and `%h`. Because `ProxyJump` essentially uses `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p`, it is actually sending the `Host` name instead of `HostName` (`1pi` instead of `raspi1`).

If you don't want to jump through the hoops of installing OpenSSH_8.2p1 or anything else, you can replace `ProxyJump 1pi` with `ProxyCommand ssh -W %n:%p 1pi` until Apple replaces the version of OpenSSH. Considering that Apple is the one who reported the bug (thanks Pierre-Olivier), I am assuming that it will be updated in the next 10.15.4 Beta.

If you're interested in source code, the bug was introduced here: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/fbe24b142915331ceb2a3a76be3dc5b6d204fddf#diff-5bfa45f3fb322e569a8101399c9c551cR1372

The bug was fixed here: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/2ab335712d084d9ccaf3f53afc3fa9535329da87#diff-5bfa45f3fb322e569a8101399c9c551cR1395

---

As an alternative to the above answer, a possibly simpler answer that will solve your problem and not make you change anything when Apple releases the fix exists.

Just add `2pi` to your `/etc/hosts` file on `raspi1`. e.g. `{IP address of 2pi} 2pi`. Assuming your IP address is 192.168.1.10, it'd be:

```
echo "192.168.1.10 2pi" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: This will likely be fixed in the next seed of 10.15.4, according to Apple.